# What if the only eigenvectors of $A$ are multiples of $x=(1,0,0)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question is from an exercise in Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra and its Applications*:

> Suppose the only eigenvectors of $A$ are multiples of $x=(1,0,0)$. True or false:
>
> (a) $A$ is not invertible.
>
> (b) $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue.
>
> (c) $A$ is not diagonalizable.

(b) has to be true. Since if $A$ has different eigenvalues, then there will be linear independent eigenvectors.

One example that I can come up with for which (a) and (c) are true is 
$$A=\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
     0&  1& 0 \\
     0& 0 & 1 \\
     0& 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

Here are my questions:

- Are there any counterexamples for (a) and (c)?
- What's the underlying picture of this problem?

Comment: The underlying picture is the theory of Jordan normal form. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: If your field is not algebraically closed, it may well be the case that the only eigenvectors are the non-zero multiples of $(1,0,0)$ and there is no repeated eigenvalue: for example, over $\mathbb R$ the characteristic polynomial could be $x(x^2+1)$.

Comment: I don't understand... you have correctly pointed out (b) must be true, so how could you have a counterexample to (b), let alone to (a) *and* (b)?

Comment: @Arturo: Ah, that's my silly typo. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @Arturo: I am pretty sure the OP meant (a) and (c). Also, I am pretty sure the question is intended to be over $\mathbb{C}$ (although I could be wrong).

Comment: @Jack: There can be no counterexample to (c), because if the matrix is diagonalizable then it necessarily must have a basis of eigenvectors, hence at least three linearly independent eigenvectors, hence not every eigenvector is a scalar multiple of $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Hmm, I'm surprised that the Jordan form comes up in the *appendix* of the Strang's book... And I find that my example is actually a Jordan matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the complex numbers, you must have a matrix that is similar to
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{array}\right),$$
where $\lambda$ is the unique eigenvalue; this follows form the theory of Jordan Canonical forms.

Over a non-algebraically closed field, you have two possibilities: either a matrix similar to one as above (if the characteristic polynomial splits as a perfect cube), or else a matrix similar to one of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccr}
\lambda & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -a\\
0 & 1 & -b
\end{array}\right),$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, and $x^2 + bx + a$ is an irreducible quadratic polynomial over your field; this follows from the theory of Rational Canonical Forms.

In either case, the matrix is invertible if and only if $\lambda\neq 0$, and the matrix is never diagonalizable.

Comment: +1. Thanks for you answer. I haven't learned the Rational Canonical Forms before. I guess it can be found in some advanced linear algebra book?

Comment: @Jack: Well, it's in Friedberg, Insel, and Spence, at least.

Comment: Also in Artin! (Ch. 12)

Answer (score 4):

In my elementary linear algebra class we did many problems like this without the Jordan Normal Form, etc, which I picked up later. So I will try to give a simpler explanation.

a) Recall that a matrix is non-invertible if it has nonzero vectors in its null space. This also means that those vectors are eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$. So what if $\text{null } A =\text{span }{(1,0,0)}?$ This is the case where an eigenvalue of $A$ is 0. However, you CANNOT conclude this from your givens, because you have no hypothesis on what the eigenvalue of $\text{span }{(1,0,0)}$ is.

b) Now, $A$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb R^3.$ This means that $A$ has a real eigenvalue, because the characteristic equation of $A$ is a cubic, so it has a real root. What if two of those roots were imaginary? Then $A$ would have its one-dimensional eigenspace, as given, but would not have a repeated eigenvalue.

c) This one is true. A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space it operates on. This means you need $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors where you only have one! An easy to remember this is that, to diagonalize a matrix $A$, you need to be able to write it as $A = PDP^{-1},$ where $P$ is an $n$ x $n$  matrix whose columns consist of eigenvectors of $A.$ Remember that $P$ is invertible if and only if it has linearly independent columns, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for a part; let the order of matrix be n then we know the very common relation n-r=1 it implies r=n-1 hence rank is less than n hence not invertible